# Is there a possibility to print the name of the class an iterator points to?

Tags: c++, oop

Assume I have a program that works according to the following hierarchy:
[image: DIAGRAM]

And I have a linked list container of `Human *` which I am iterating over with `std::list<Human *>::iterator human`. The following iterator can point either `Men`, `Women` and `Flying Men`. Is there a possibility, maybe something like `typeid(*human).name()` that will return the name of the class that the pointed object belongs to? When I use `typeid.name()` I get `class Human *`.

Comment: you can always create top base class with virtual std::string toString() { /*class name*/ }, which will return actuall class name. toString() should be overriden in each subclass.

Comment: That's that trivial solution, I wanted to know if the power of C++ can help me.

Comment: @marcin they should be implemented, not overridden.

Comment: 1) typeid only distinguishes between types if there is a virtual function member of the class. 2) Try typeid(*(*human)).name(). 3) This would NOT be a cross platform way of doing it, since .name() isn't required to reflect your code, be unique, or even be human readable.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? This looks like the beginning of a bad solution to a dispatch problem.

Comment: I think that if toString in base class would be abstract then "implemented" would be OK, but otherwise its overriding. ie. Men::toString would override Human::toString.

Comment: @HonkyTonk The problem I'm trying to solve is saving data in a file similar to .ini file that should hold the properties of the objects in the container while being as readable as it gets (for humans).

Comment: Ok. Then I'm guessing that you want a way to let different types have different `Serialize` implementation but it has to work in a way that lets you serialize an object even if you only have a `Human*` to work with. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting an execution path in runtime based on type inspection is *bad* since it places knowledge where it shouldn't be and makes it harder to add new types since all checks have to be expanded with the new type id.

Instead, define an interface that allows all types that need it create their own versions. Here is a compilable example that you can copy and play around with. Notice that adding a new type that should be serialized doesn't change any code in existing classes and no new tests are needed. And, as a bonus, everything is type checked at compile time, making it impossible to add a call with an object of the wrong type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class Output {
public:
  // Whatever operations needed
  int Write(int value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
  }
};

class Human {
public:
  virtual ~Human() {}

  virtual int Serialize(Output& output) = 0;
};

class Men : public Human {
public:
  int Serialize(Output& output) {
    return output.Write(17);
  }
};

class Women : public Human {
public:
  int Serialize(Output& output) {
    return output.Write(42);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Output output;

  Men men1;
  Men men2;
  Women women1;
  Women women2;

  std::list<Human*> toSerialize;

  toSerialize.push_back(&men1);
  toSerialize.push_back(&women1);
  toSerialize.push_back(&men2);
  toSerialize.push_back(&women1);

  BOOST_FOREACH(Human* human, toSerialize) {
    human->Serialize(output);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're guiding me to use the right *design pattern*?

Comment: @Quaker After you clarified what problem you were really solving, yes, showing a better way to do it seemed like the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeid` on the object `**human` itself, rather than the pointer, which always has type `Human*` whatever it points to. As long as `Human` is polymorphic (that is, it declares at least one virtual function), that will give you the type info for the dynamic type of the object.

Note that the name is not necessarily human-readable, or even unique; my compiler gives the mangled name `3Man` if the pointer points to type `Man`, and other compilers may give other nastiness. If you want a nice human-readable name, you'll have to declare your own virtual member function to return one.

Comment: @Quaker: Good, in that case it's also polymorphic, so `typeid` should work.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Just to note, this is not *guaranteed* to work by the standard. The name from classid.name() does not need to be human readable, unique, or reflect the written name of the class in any way :-/.

Answer (score 0):

No. Typeinfo is the best reflection you're going to get. If you really need this, make a virtual member function that returns the proper names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but your classes must have a virtual function. The best place would be to use a virtual destructor, since it is most likely needed sooner rather than later anyway.

Also note that `typeid` is not defined to give you a readable name. If it does with the compilers you currently target, great. If not, you may need to add a virtual function like `const std::string &className() const` to get what you want.